# How to fill empty CSS grid columns based on visibility of siblings

Tags: css, css-grid

I have the following grid -

Parent - `grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);`

Child1 - `grid-column: 1 / span 3;`

Child2 - `grid-column: 4 / span -1;`

```css
.box {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 5px;
  height: 50px;
}

.child1 {
  grid-column: 1 / span 3;
  background: red;
}

.child2 {
  grid-column: 4 / -1;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
</div>
```

Is it possible for child2 to start at line 1 when Child1 is hidden? Now when Child1 is "display:none", the grid leaves 3 empty columns. I would like to shift child2 to line1.
Would be great if someone could guide me on this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you put up a minimal reproducible example so we can see more clearly what the problem is [link]https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like below. The trick is to not define the number of columns and they will only get created when needed.

```css
.box {
  display:grid;
  grid-auto-columns:  1fr; /* equal width columns */
  grid-auto-flow:column; /* column flow */
  grid-gap: 5px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 2px solid;
}

.child1 {
  grid-column: span 3;
  background: red;
}

.child2 {
  grid-column: span 9;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
below we have 12 columns
<div class="box">
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
</div>

below we have 9 columns
<div class="box">
  <div class="child1" style="display:none"></div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Temani - But I want specifically 12 columns. So auto columns may not work

Comment: @BLACKPANTHER 12 or 9 columns won't make any difference if your element will take all of them. Why you need 12 columns? if such requirement is important you should edit your question and add a more accurate use case

Comment: The design requirement is a 12 Grid when desktop and 6 grid when tablet etc. That's why I mentioned it as repeat(12) specifically

Comment: @BLACKPANTHER you question requirement is to make the child2 span all the columns when alone, right?